# do I download the image twice if use pods to cache the image and download it asynchronously?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, kingfisher

I am new in programming and in iOS development, I try to use kingfisher to cache and download the image asynchronously.

I have one downloadURL, and the downloaded image from that link will be used for 2 image view. for blurryImageView and for posterImageView.

the blurryImageView will be used as the background, if in case the image from the user is not in the desired vertical horizontal ratio like the picture below

[image]

my question is, if I download from that one link and will be used for 2 image view, am I actually download it twice or just once?

here is the simplified code I use :

```
import Kingfisher

        @IBOutlet weak var posterImageView: ImageView!
         @IBOutlet weak var blurryImageView: ImageView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

         guard let urlPoster = URL(string: imagePathString) else {return}
         blurryImageView.kf.setImage(with: urlPoster)
         posterImageView.kf.setImage(with: urlPoster)

        }
```

as you can see in the code above, the image will be downloaded asynchronously, and when `posterImageView.kf.setImage(with: urlPoster)` is triggered, the image is ( I assume ) still not yet finished downloaded when from `blurryImageView.kf.setImage(with: urlPoster)` . so I am worried it will be downloaded twice which is not efficient. I want it to be downloaded only once. what should I do if I only want to download it oncee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry it won't download again. If you read the kingfisher docs it mentions that once the images are downloaded they are cached. So the next time you call the image from that url it's picked up from the cache.

Here is the line from the kingfisher docs

> Kingfisher will download the image from url, send it to both the
>   memory cache and the disk cache, and display it in imageView. When you
>   use the same code later, the image will be retrieved from cache and
>   shown immediately.